# How to get facebook friends emails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala, omnicontacts-gem

I am working on `ruby on rails` application and here I need Facebook friends `email ID's`

I need to send an invitation to all of my friends(Facebook friends) as join in to my application by email.

So I need to get their `email Id's`. I have tried with omnicontacts Facebook, Koala and Graph API but I did not get `email id's` of my friends, I can get their **names, uid, etc...** but I need `email ID's` of my friends.

Can any one please suggest me any gem in `rails` application to sort out this problem with small snippet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook probably doesn't give out that info.... it can be used for all sorts of nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook graph api email permission for more details use this reference https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph

Comment: I did not find any proper method to get all my friends email id's by using graph api and koala can you please provide me any link which will explain in detail.

Comment: Facebook never give you any friend's email only person's email who authorize your app with email permission.

Comment: No I can able to get authorized persons email'id, but I need Friends email id's to send invitation to join with my app

Comment: Facebook don't give any method to get friends email address.You can notify user's friend by app notification,